# If $G$ is perfect, show $G/N$ is also perfect (for a $N\trianglelefteq G$)

Tags: group-theory

> If $G$ is perfect, show $G/N$ is also perfect (for a $N\trianglelefteq G$)

I have some proof, but I don't think it right.

#### Proof?

Choose a $Ng\in G/N$ then since $g\in G$ and $G$ is perfect, then there must exists a $h,k\in G$ such that $[h,k]=g$.

Now consider $[Nh, Nk] = (Nh^{-1})(Nk^{-1})(Nh)(Nk) = N (h^{-1}k^{-1}hk) = Ng$. $\square$

#### However

The proper definition of a perfect group is

> $G$ is perfect if it's commutator subgroup equals $G$.

Or $[G,G]=G$, where the commutator subgroup is defined as

> $[G,G] = \langle \{[g,h]: g,h\in G\}\rangle$

Now I'm a bit confused with this definition. This implies that $[G,G]$ is the group generated by the commutators $[g,h]$. I guess this implies that if not all elements of $[G,G]$ can be written as $[g,h]$, but for example some can be written as a product of commutators.

This would imply that the step "*then there must exists a $h,k\in G$ such that $[h,k]=g$*" is faulty.

Is this really an issue? And what is the best way to fix this issue?

Comment: It is really an issue.

Comment: Ok, it seemed to trivial ;) I'll give it some more thought first

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ is perfect, that is $G=G'$, then $(G/N)'=G'N/N=GN/N=G/N$.

Answer (score 1):

If $G/N$ has a nontrivial abelian quotient $G/N\to A$, then so does $G$, as you can take the composition $G\to G/N\to A$ with the projection.